# Suspend doesn't happen at all

Tags: suspend

I have an dell inspiron n5110 with nvidia graphic. It has 12.10 and windows installed on. It was working fine until a morning when I turned it on an message appeared which said ubuntu cannot found your graphic (sth like that) and it asked if it could reconfigure the graphic card. i have pushed the button nothing actually happened
After a reset ubuntu graphic interface started nice but when i was going to suspend in any way, apparently, nothing happens. even the screen doesn't turn black.
I should mention after switching to windows it couldn't find my nvidia graphic but after reinstalling the driver i could sleep my laptop in windows. But it still not suspending in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try running from terminal the following,

```
sudo /etc/acpi/sleep.sh
```

Comment: after doing that it has been suspended properly but how can i add this function to the suspend button?

Comment: Go to `/etc/acpi` and open `sleepbtn` in gedit. Now change the `$KEY_SLEEP` to `$KEY_SUSPEND` and see if it works. You might need sudo permission to edit the file. Also try adding a `sudo` infront of that last line; `sudo acpi_fakekey $KEY_SLEEP'